# Using objects compiled with /NOAUTOINHERIT inside c# projects

Tags: c#, cil

I have a DLL containing an empty object which I want to use as a base object. This object was compiled directly from cil using ilasm.exe with `/NOAUTOINHERIT`, so it does not inherit from System.Object. Visual studio loads the DLL just fine, and the app compiles just fine, but when I try to use this object in code (by using classes that inherit this empty base object) I get a runtime exception saying:

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'BaseObject' from assembly 'AssemblyName,
Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the parent does not exist.'
```

We're creating a compiler using c# and want to use the primitive types within the language in our runtime helper. We're gonna compile into CIL and within CIL use our primitives DLL and runtime helper and that /NOAUTOINHERIT flag. We want to write the runtime helper in c# and use the primitives DLL as well, which requires loading it, which causes the exception.
Is there anything to do about this? Any config, project option, compiler option, ilasm option, that could enable me to use this base object inside my C# project?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want a class which does not inherit from `object`? I'm assuming the answer "remove that ilasm option" is out of the question?

Comment: Not sure if it's verifiable or even valid to have such a type, I think it's just for testing

Comment: We're creating a compiler using c# and want to use the primitive types within the language in our runtime helper. We're gonna compile into CIL and within CIL use our primitives DLL and runtime helper and that /NOAUTOINHERIT flag. We want to write the runtime helper in c# and use the primitives DLL as well, which requires loading it, which causes the exception